# Why my java awt code runs very slow?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I'm an Android developer But now I need to develop a desktop socket server using awt.I write a very small demo to show some lines using Shape,but it's very slow.

```
public class Main {

    public static void drawLine(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2,GeneralPath generalPath,int size){
        Line2D line2D = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        Line2D line2D2 = new Line2D.Double(x2, y2 + size, x1, y1 + size);
        generalPath.append(line2D, false);
        generalPath.append(line2D2, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SocketServer socketServer = new SocketServer(8890);
        socketServer.startListen();

        Window w = new Window(null) {
            GeneralPath generalPath = new GeneralPath();
            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = ((Graphics2D) g);

                Vector<Action> v = socketServer.v;
                for (; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
                    Action action = v.get(i);
                    if(action.type != action.ACTION_DOWN){
                        Action preAction = v.get(i-1);
                        drawLine(preAction.x,preAction.y,action.x,action.y,generalPath,1);
                    }
                }

                setShape(generalPath);
            }

            @Override
            public void update(Graphics g) {
                paint(g);
            }
        };
        w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
        w.setVisible(true);
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            w.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to draw real-time trails from the socket,so I need repaint all the time.I also need to provide the click-through behavior so I must use shape.

I know little about awt.**Can anybody tell me the problem why my demo runs so slow after drawing some lines?
Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are doing multiple things in the main thread. Consider using background tasks. This will make UI performance much better.

Comment: Your suggestion is very useful,but after changing drawLine() to a new Thread it also take too many cpu resource.Confused.

Comment: The blocker is your socket connection.. I believe you are reading data from socket to draw line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good about Server and Socket things, but if you added the option '-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true', it could boost up rendering a little bit, as Java2D and AWT in general is not known for its speed.

Hope it will help :)